# How exactly does one calculate the proper filter capacitors for the 567 tone detector?

Tags: audio, filter, sound, decoder

I'm making a wireless remote control system using the 555 and 567 IC's.

Everything is working OK with the exception of the tone detector, yet I can hear the tone when I hook up a speaker to my circuit at the point where the tone detector can pick the same noise up.

I think it comes down to the input filter capacitor and output filter capacitor connected to the 567.

Currently I use 2.2uF and 4.7uF capacitors as filter capacitors, but there is nowhere online that dictates an equation for such capacitors and there's nothing that tells me what resistance to follow so I can even figure out a capacitor value.

The tone I'm trying to detect is a tone at 5Khz.

What equation do I use for the input and output filter capacitor for the 567 to successfully detect a 5Khz tone?

Comment: Schematic? Link to datasheet - for the 567 at least?

Answer (score 5):

**Making it go:**

It is likely that the lack of output is due to you not having allowed for the fact that the LM567 has an "open collector" output.
   (Rl on pin 8 in the diagram below. Output is low when tone is 'detected'.)

It needs a resistor or similar to V+ to operate.
Without this the device is about as good at detecting tones as is a pillar of salt.

**Design:**

The Philips data sheet makes design easy [tm].

[**Philips LM567 data sheet**](http://pira.cz/pdf/lm567.pdf)
FAR better for design and understanding than TI version.
Page 408 contains most of what you need to know, but there is also much more there that is useful.

[image]

Basics:

**Frequency** = f0 = 1/(1.1 x R1 x C1)
   ( 2k <= R1 <= 20k)

**Bandwidth** = 1070 x (Vi/(f0 x C2))^1/2
20 mV <= Vi < 200 mV - input voltage

**Output filter capacitor C3** - From Philips data sheet page 409
"The value of C3 is generally non-critical. C3 sets the band edge of a low-pass filter which attenuates frequencies outside the
detection band to eliminate spurious outputs. If C3 is too small,
frequencies just outside the detection band will switch the output
stage on and off at the beat frequency, or the output may pulse
on and off during the turn-on transient. If C3 is too large, turn-on
and turn-off of the output stage will be delayed until the voltage on C3 passes the
threshold voltage. (Such delay may be desirable to avoid spurious
outputs due to transient frequencies.) 
**A typical minimum value for C3 is 2 x C2

See Philips data sheet for other components.

**_______________________________________**

[**TI LM567 data sheet here**](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567c.pdf) - 
Detailed  design requirements are given in section 11.2.1.2 on page 14.
Shockingly poor wrt applications.

[Natsemi](http://www.funkcom.ch/pdf/ne567.pdf) - looks familiar :-(.

[Here is an online calculator for all tone related components](http://www.vk2zay.net/calculators/lm567.php)

[Features & parameters explained](http://www.homemade-circuits.com/2013/03/lm567-tone-decoder-ic-features-and.html) they say

[Lots of ideas - each image links to a page](https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=lm567+application+notes&num=100&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis-LLcroTPAhULkpQKHfa2DtoQsAQINg&biw=1120&bih=617)

[LM567 used in IR controller](http://www.wimb.net/index.php?s=electr&page=7)

---

A very old but useful IC - I used these in my Masters thesis hardware 35+ years ago :-).

Comment: +1 for making reference to C2 equation in the Philips LM567 data sheet

Comment: +1 for the much better Philips datasheet.  I just got bit by the TI/NatSemi datasheet and it's bad design guideline.  Using an R1 < 2kOhm doesn't go well.

Answer (score 1):

> but there is nowhere online that dictates an equation for such
>   capacitors and there's nothing that tells me what resistance to follow
>   so I can even figure out a capacitor value

It's really easy to find this information: -

[image]

[image]

Comment: I can't accept this answer because I'm trying to figure out how to calculate values of C3 and C2. What you and other sources online have demonstrated is how to determine the detection frequency using C1 and R1.