# LM567 understand math to get right frequency

Tags: audio

I am trying to create a little module that can listen to a specific tone, like high peak that are not audible from humans, probably 11+ kHz.

Looking at this project http://www.instructables.com/id/Sonic-Control/ I have bought the same items but apparently when I had the microphone, it is always blinking the LEDs but when I get the a jack wired to my PC, it response to some low frequency.

I am not 100% sure what are the values and formula to work out the right capacitor and resistor values.

Comment: There's not even a question. Beyond a link to some tutorial there's no good description of your problem either.

Comment: @Dampmaskin the question was to help out figure out the right value if I want to  filter 11Khz or 12khz. But MCG actually answered below

Comment: The datasheet in the article gives the formulas for the LM567.  The article also has an online frequency calculator.

Comment: @max246 Human higher audio limit is ~20kHz, give or take (more take), less with age. 11kHz is quite audible and can irritate people, though it can exist as a higher harmonic from whatever source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading through the [DATASHEET](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm567c.pdf) for the LM576, the formula is written on page 9.

I assume what you want to know is the 'center frequency'. To do this, just follow the formula on the datasheet:
[image]

It is all there if you read through it. Alternatively, the link you provided to the instructible project even has a [LINK](http://www.vk2zay.net/calculators/lm567.php) to a page that will calculate the bandwidth and center frequency for you.

All the information you are requesting is there if you look for it.

Comment: thank you so much, I got a bit confused but this is very good answer.

Comment: FYI: I found the design procedure and additional notes in the Philips datasheet more helpful than the TI/National Semi datasheets.  With the TI datasheet I had resistor values that were too low for stable operation.

Comment: Another good answer is here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/257030/109442